Stuck on 20.04.6 due to fwupd -- cannot do upgrade
I had a system disaster that made me go back to an old backup.  My machine is at Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, and I cannot get it to upgrade further.  This is at least partly because fwupd is being held back.
I see that there was a problem that caused this, discussed at Kept back upgrade of fwupd.  The discussion there seemed sure that the problem would solve itself if I somehow kept packages installed.  I do not have fwupd-signed installed, and I cannot see how to get it.  Apt won't install it, and neither will synaptic.
In response to a comment, I switched from visual apps to the command-line, and here's what apt-get did:
root@plato-f:~# apt-get --quiet --assume-yes dist-upgrade
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages have been kept back:
  fwupd-signed gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
root@plato-f:~#

What can I do now?

In case it matters, I do have fwupd and fwupdate installed.

We need to see some actual error messages, not just vague verbal descriptions.

I hope apt-get and its output is actual enough for you -- I have edited it into the original question.
